# Flutter Android App - Fonts look aliased / lower resolution

Tags: android, flutter

I have noticed my tabs rendering, and the bottom navigation bar are looking a little off (aliased), as you can see from the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s02FT.jpg):

However, I have a drawer that looks okay when I pull it up:

```
  child: Scaffold(
    floatingActionButtonLocation: CenterDockedFloatingActionButtonLocation(),
    floatingActionButtonAnimator: NoScalingAnimation(),
    floatingActionButton: uiFloatingActionButton(),
    body: Center(
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          container = Container(
            foregroundDecoration: BoxDecoration(
              backgroundBlendMode: BlendMode.darken,
              color: Provider.of<MenuServicosViewModel>(context).status == ServicosDrawerStatus.Show ? Colors.black26 : Colors.transparent,
            ),
            child: _widgetTabs.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
          ),
          drawer,
        ],
      ),
    ),
```

[Drawer showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Goh6m.jpg)

[Login screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8UpW.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I was using the backgroundBlendMode with the foregroundDecoration to darken the background, which causes the layers under it to appear pixelated, even when set to transparent.
The whole app was being displayed under this layer.

The solution was to assign no foregroundDecoration when the layer wasn`t being displayed.

from:

```
foregroundDecoration: BoxDecoration(
              backgroundBlendMode: BlendMode.darken,
              color: Provider.of<MenuServicosViewModel>(context).status == ServicosDrawerStatus.Show ? Colors.black26 : Colors.transparent,
            ),
```

to:

```
foregroundDecoration: Provider.of<MenuServicosViewModel>(context).status == ServicosDrawerStatus.Show
                    ? BoxDecoration(
                        backgroundBlendMode: BlendMode.darken,
                        color: Colors.black26,
                      )
                    : null,
```